# MultiValueKeyDictError Django while uploading csv file

Tags: django

I am trying to upload csv file from user and display it on the template. I have searched a lot for error but none has helped. So I decided to take help from this great community. Here is my code

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def offlineResults(request):
    screenNametestList = []
    friendsCountList = []
    followersCountList = []
    favouriteCountList = []
    listedCountList = []
    statusCountList = []
    genEnabledList = []
    protectedList = []
    verifiedList = []
    defaultProfileList = []
    botsList = []

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['filecsv']:
        csv_file = request.FILES['filecsv']
        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        next(io_string)  # skipping 1st line because 1st line contains header file
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
            screenNametest = column[0]
            screenNametestList.append(screenNametest)
            friends_countTest = column[1]
            friendsCountList.append(friends_countTest)
            followers_countTest = column[2]
            followersCountList.append(followers_countTest)
            favouriteCountTest = column[3]
            favouriteCountList.append(favouriteCountTest)
            listedCountTest = column[4]
            listedCountList.append(listedCountTest)
            statusCountTest = column[5]
            statusCountList.append(statusCountTest)
            geoEnabledTest = column[6]
            genEnabledList.append(geoEnabledTest)
            protectedTest = column[7]
            protectedList.append(protectedTest)
            verifiedTest = column[8]
            verifiedList.append(verifiedTest)
            defaultProfileTest = column[9]
            defaultProfileList.append(defaultProfileTest)
            botsTest = column[10]
            botsList.append(botsTest)

        dicCSV = {
            'sc': screenNametestList,
            'friendCount': friendsCountList,
            'followersCount': followersCountList,
            'favouriteCount': favouriteCountList,
            'listedCount': listedCountList,
            'statusCount': statusCountList,
            'geoEnabled': genEnabledList,
            'protected': protectedList,
            'verified': verifiedList,
            'defaultProfile': defaultProfileList,
            'bots': botsList
        }

        return JsonResponse(dicCSV)
```

**offline.html**

```
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center"><b><u>Offline Results</u></b></h1>
        <form class="md-form mt-4" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="file-field">

                <input type="file" name="filecsv" accept=".csv">

                <button type="submit" id="load_csv" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="table-responsive mt-4">
            <table class="table" id="data_table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ScreenName</th>
                    <th scope="col">FriendCount</th>
                    <th scope="col">FollowerCount</th>
                    <th scope="col">FavouriteCount</th>
                    <th scope="col">listedCount</th>
                    <th scope="col">statusCount</th>
                    <th scope="col">geoEnabled</th>
                    <th scope="col">Protected</th>
                    <th scope="col">Verified</th>
                    <th scope="col">DefaultProfile</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div><!--end container-->
```

**ajax part**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#load_csv').on('click',function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: {% url 'offlineResults' %},
                method: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                {#contentType: false,#}
                {#cache: false,#}
                {#processData: false,#}
                success: function (jsonData)
                {
                    $('#load_csv').val('');
                    $('#data_table').DataTable({
                        data : jsonData,
                        columns: [
                            {   data:   'sc'},
                            {   data:   'friendCount'},
                            {   data:   'followersCount'},
                            {   data:   'favouriteCount'},
                            {   data:   'listedCount'},
                            {   data:   'statusCount'},
                            {   data:   'geoEnabled'},
                            {   data:   'protected'},
                            {   data:   'verified'},
                            {   data:   'defaultProfile'}

                        ]
                    });
                }
            })
        });

    });
```

It generates the following error

> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filecsv'
>       [11/Apr/2019 20:41:48] "POST /offlineResults/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17525

What I am doing wrong. Help please

**The entire traceback**

> Internal Server Error: /offlineResults/ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Mustajab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py",
>   line 77, in **getitem**
>       list_ = super().**getitem**(key) KeyError: 'filecsv'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Mustajab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Mustajab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\Mustajab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Mustajab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
>   line 54, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "F:\Final Year Project\FYPDjango\FYPapp\views.py", line 64, in offlineResults
>       if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['filecsv']:   File "C:\Users\Mustajab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py",
>   line 79, in **getitem**
>       raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filecsv'
>   [11/Apr/2019 20:41:48] "POST /offlineResults/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17525

Comment: Does debug gives you more detailed error, maybe with some line numbers?

Comment: Show us the entire error trace.

Comment: Try and narrow down where the problem is. Does it work if you don't use ajax?

Comment: `if ... and request.FILES['filecsv']` is failing. First you should use `request.FILES.get('filecsv')` because it might not be there. Second, you're not uploading the file in your ajax request. Search here on SO for how to upload a file with ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: thanks @dirkgroten I will try that

Comment: @scriptmonster, I have updated the question with entire traceback. Please check this

Comment: The error is as I said. The key “filecsv” doesn’t exist. Always use `get()` or `getlist()`  if you don’t know for sure it exists.

Comment: @dirkgroten when I uses `get()`, it gives another error, `ValueError: The view FYPapp.views.offlineResults didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: That’s because your `if` condition is False (you should add an `else` and return a page with error in that case). Did you read my comment????? You’re not posting a filecsv.

Comment: @dirkgroten, please don't get irritated with me. Just please tell me what should I do to get this file upload successfully.

Comment: I gave you all the instructions needed to solve your issue. Reformulated now in an answer. We’re not here to write your code.

Comment: Thanks, @dirkgroten. At least I get to know the error. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you’re accessing a key that doesn’t exist in the dictionary. When you’re checking if a value in a dictionary exists, as you are doing in you `if request.FILES[‘filecsv’]` you should use `get()` instead of subscript (`[]`) to avoid a `KeyError`. So:

```
if request.FILES.get('filecsv')
```

Once you change that you’ll notice the `if` condition is `False` and you’ll get another error because your view is returning nothing in that case. Always return an HttpResponse. Maybe the same page with an error message here.

Now the main issue is that your Ajax call doesn’t submit any data. It just does a POST request without any data. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) how to upload a file using jquery ajax.